# JavaScript正規表現でマッチした全ての値を配列で取得する

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

JavaScriptで下記データから大括弧[]内のデータだけ、抜き出す良い方法を教えてください。

```
a[hogehoge] b[fugafuga] c[piyopiyo]
```

求める出力結果としては、["hogehoge", "fugafuga", "piyopiyo"] になります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

別回答のコメントより

> 大括弧[ ]なしで出力する方法はどうすれば

ということなので、capture を使う方法を紹介しておきます。

```
var s = 'a[hogehoge] b[fugafuga] c[piyopiyo]';
var r = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;

var a = [];
while ((m = r.exec(s)) != null) {
  a.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(a);
```

このように正規表現内に `()` を追加してキャプチャした上で、 `exec()` をループで回してそれを配列に詰め込めば、大括弧なしの文字列を取得できます。長くなってしまうのが玉に瑕な感じですが、参考まで。

Answer (score 2):

配列を得るには`/g`オプションを使います。

```
'a[hogehoge] b[fugafuga] c[piyopiyo]'.match(/\[[^\]]*\]/g)
// ["[hogehoge]", "[fugafuga]", "[piyopiyo]"]
```

上記の結果には[]が含まれてしまいますが、JavaScriptでは正規表現の後読みがサポートされていないため先頭の[が除去できません。(後ろの]は`(?=\])`で対処できます。)

なので`Array.prototype.map`を使用して

```
'a[hogehoge] b[fugafuga] c[piyopiyo]'
     .match(/\[[^\]]*\]/g)
     .map(function(s)s.substring(1, s.length - 1))
```

と後処理を加えてやればよいと思います。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。説明不足で申し訳ありませんが、大括弧[ ]なしで出力する方法はどうすればよろしいでしょうか？求める出力結果としては、["hogehoge", "fugafuga", "piyopiyo"] になります。

Comment: JavaScriptでは正規表現の後読みがサポートされていないため、大括弧を取り除いての出力はできないのですね。

Comment: 正規表現に拘らなければ、回答の後ろに`.map(function(s)s.substring(1,s.length-1))`などを付けてやればよいかと。

Comment: なるほどありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

既に解決されていますが、`split()` を使う方法もあります。

```
'a[hogehoge] b[fugafuga] c[piyopiyo]'
  .split(/^[^\[]*\[|\][^\[\]]*\[|\][^\]]*$/)
  .slice(1,-1);
=> hogehoge, fugafuga, piyopiyo
```