# javascript/typescriptにて文字列から特定の値を抜き出し変数に格納する

Tags: javascript, 正規表現, typescript

```
let title1 = "2017年 3月号 / No.98";
let title2 = "2017年 10月号 / No.105";
```

上記のような文字列を格納した変数があり、この中から年の値(2017)をyear、月の値(3 or 10)をmonth、No.の値(98 or 105)をnumberといった変数に格納する場合、どのような正規表現を利用し、取得すれば良いでしょうか？
ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6849/javascript%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E5%85%A8%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%A7%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B　こんなのも役に立つかと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[文字列.match(正規表現)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) でマッチした結果が配列で得られます。
数値は`(\d+)`の様にマッチする部分を指定します。
`/`は、`\/`のようにエスケープします。
（間のスペースが複数だったり単数だったりゆらぎがある場合にはその部分も[正規表現](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)とする必要があります。）
（`result[0]`はマッチした全体、以降は`( )`で指定した部分マッチ）
（`result =`の部分は`[dummy, year, month, number] =`にも[できます](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)。(ブラウザによっては未サポートであることに注意下さい)`dummy`が必要なのは最初がマッチの全体なため）
以下例：

```js
let title1 = "2017年 3月号 / No.98";

let result = title1.match(/(\d+)年 (\d+)月号 \/ No.(\d+)/);
let year = result[1];
let month = result[2];
let number = result[3];
console.log("year:", year);
console.log("month:", month);
console.log("number:", number);
```